# At which moment exactly is it possible to select bonus power in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When **exactly** (which step, which moment) can i select bonus power in  following scenarios?

1. Create from scrap new ME3 character
2. Create new game+ second playthrough new character
3. Create new character with ME2 import

I already know that you can unlock bonus powers by talking to squad members.

I already know that you can buy bonus powers at med-bay bonuspower store.

Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a Bonus Power at any time on the Normandy after the game has started--only ones you've unlocked of course.

If you have access to the Normandy you can change it at any time by going on the Normandy and using one of the terminals in the Med Bay. You can't set it anywhere else mid-game, meaning no switches in missions.

Additionally, when starting a New Game + you get to pick one Bonus Power right when you start the game, so you'll have it before you reach the Normandy.

If you import a character from ME2 you still have to wait till you get to the Normandy (and unlock a bonus power) before you can set one.

Comment: With the ME2 imported character, it acts like scenario number one up there.  Just bear in mind that not all bonus powers are available at the start of the game.  Some are only unlocked midway through the game after talking to various party members.

Comment: @RESPAWN awesome, thanks. So importing doesn't keep any of your bonus powers?

Comment: Also, for the sake of specificity, the console to change bonus powers is in the Normandy Medical Bay.

Comment: @BenBrocka Sadly no.  You just get the skill point credits for your bonus powers.  I had to wait until half the game to get Reave back.  :(

Comment: Brocka wrote : "Additionally, when starting a New Game + you get to pick one Bonus Power right when you start the game, so you'll have it before you reach the Normandy. "
I had this opportunity once. but in midgame, i decided to start a new 'new game+' and loaded the same save from 1st playthrough. This time i didn't get a chance to pick bonus power. Unfair.